# oAuth exception #200 while trying to post to groups after recent Facebook maintenance

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

`"message":"OAuthException: (#200) Insufficient permission to post to target on behalf of the viewer","trace":"[]","code":0`

This message started to appear randomly after the recent Facebook maintenance actions.

My users are generating this error while trying to share into their groups.

Any thought on how to solve this?.

Comment: Have you tried with a fresh access token, or debugged the existing one? Might be they messed something up with that during their outage. I'd try to send the user through the login flow again first.

Comment: Yes I did, all tokens are valid, up to date, and have user_groups in their scope :(

Comment: Oh and also publish_stream and public_Actions of course

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When the application request the permission, you need choose Public, not Only Me.

Comment: but this occurs only with a specific groups, not with all of the groups

Comment: Is there a way to check if the user has selected Only Me so that user can be notified/requested to change permission in order to proceed with posting to the group

Comment: To change "Only Me" to "Public", sometimes you have to clear all permission -> saved -> changed permission again while generating User token. This worked for me. Hope this will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 5):

Check Your app's privacy settings is public.Otherwise make it to public.

Here are steps:

Go to settings in your facebook account. Then click on Apps menu. Then choose your developer application and click on it. In top, you will see 'App visibility and post audience' and choose drop down showing at right. choose public in dropdown options

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission issue. Talk to the support team of Facebook Developer.

Comment: If you can't send an exact answer or if it's just a suggestion, you can leave a comment