# Post directly to facebook group wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been trying to post some data from my webpage directly to a facebook group wall. Is is possible to achieve?
Here's a code i used:

```
$.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
FB.init({
      appId      : myAppId,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.0'
    });
FB.api('/groupId/feed', 'post', { link: 'linkToMyPage', name: 'Name' } , function(response) {
          if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occured');
          } else {
            alert('Success!');
          }
        });
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [oAuth exception #200 while trying to post to groups after recent Facebook maintenance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535885/oauth-exception-200-while-trying-to-post-to-groups-after-recent-facebook-mainte)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By comparing your code against Facebook's sample code, I noticed that you need to capitialize `"POST"`, also their code nests `{ link: 'linkToMyPage', name: 'Name' }'` within an Object block. So I am thinking you should replace the link and name with something similar to:

```
"object": {
            "link": linkToMyPage,
            "name": 'Name'
        }
```

Here is the [API doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/group/feed), which describes how to publish to a Group feed.

Comment: Just tried this:        FB.api("/id/feed", "POST",
      {
          "object": {
              "message": "This is a test message",
              "link": "link",
              "name": "Random name"
          }
      }, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "name" is not a valid field. You need to remove it. You can only post a message with a link. The username is inherent within your current access token. (I assume you've performed a login before executing this code). Remove the 'Name' entry in your object, and let me know if it works.

Comment: Oh, i see. I tried this:   FB.login(function(){
   FB.api('/groupId/feed', 'post', {message: 'mymessage', link: 'mylink'});
  }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});. It works if i use /me/feed, but as soon as im changing it to /groupID/feed it does nothing.

Comment: Can you paste the Response here? (Instead of triggering an alert, print the response)

Comment: code: 200
message: "(#200) Insufficient permission to post to target on behalf of the viewer"
type: "OAuthException". Do i need some kind of a access token?

Comment: Have you logged in as a user?

Comment: Yes i did. I'm probably missing something really obvious, i'm new to this, sorry.

Comment: Take a look (here)[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0]. I believe you lack sufficient permissions to write to a group wall. What happens when you GET the permissions via: `GET /{user-id}/permissions`

Comment: I've got permissions granted for :"installed", "public_profile", "publish_actions", "user_groups".

Comment: Got this idea from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535885/oauth-exception-200-while-trying-to-post-to-groups-after-recent-facebook-mainte Remove the app from your installed apps in your facebook privacy settings. Login to your app again, but this time as it requests publish permissions, you need to allow publish-rights to Public, not just My Friends, or Only Me. Does doing that change things?