# Cannot post to Facebook using iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating an iOS app. I need to post some links to Facebook events using my app. I have integrated Facebook SDK. By using Facebook Graph API, i found the code for the same and it works fine in Graph API Explorer. But it does not working in my app. When trying to post the link to Facebook,it shows the following error. I am using Xcode 7.3 and iOS 9.

```
error=Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=403, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=(#200) Insufficient permission to post to target on behalf of the viewer, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=200, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 200;
        "fbtrace_id" = DWR8SW4K1Ls;
        message = "(#200) Insufficient permission to post to target on behalf of the viewer";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 403;
```

My code is given below.

```
-(void)postToFacebook
{

    if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {

        [self post];
        // TODO: publish content.
    } else {
       FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                               fromViewController:self
                                          handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                                              if(error)
                                              {
                                                  NSLog(@"error=%@",error);
                                              }
                                              else{
                                                  [self post];
                                              }

                                              //TODO: process error or result.
                                          }];
    }
}

 -(void)post
    {

        FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                      initWithGraphPath:3466734743/feed
                                      parameters:@{ @"link": @"http://www.dhip.in/ofc/metatest.html",}
                                      HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            // Insert your code here

            if(error)
            {
                NSLog(@"error=%@",error);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"success");

            }
        }];

    }
```

And i have looked into https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9 and tried all the combination of LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in my info.plist.Please help me.What is the problem? Why i can't post to Facebook?

Comment: Check the error with this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19653226/3202193

Answer (score 0):

```
SLComposeViewController *fbCompose; 

  if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
              fbCompose=[[SLComposeViewController alloc]init];
              fbCompose=[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
              [fbCompose setInitialText:@"My Score in AlphaMarics is"];
              [fbCompose addImage:image];

              [self presentViewController:fbCompose animated:YES completion:nil];

     }
     [fbCompose setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
      {
               NSString * fbOutput=[[NSString alloc]init];
               switch (result){
                        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                                 fbOutput=@"You Post is cancelled";
                                 break;

                        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                                 fbOutput=@"Your post Posted Succesfully";
                                 break;

                        default:
                                 break;
               }
               UIAlertView * fbAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:fbOutput delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
               [fbAlert show];
      }];
```